# Legacy Claris Home Page website uses X-SAS-WINDOW, can it be removed?

Tags: html, metadata

I’ve been given a legacy website created in Claris Home Page. I did a wget on it, and have all the HTML and images from it working. However, it has stuff in the header such as:

```
<X-SAS-WINDOW TOP=66 BOTTOM=480 LEFT=8 RIGHT=538>
```

I’ve not been able to find any references to `X-SAS-WINDOW`. I’m going to guess that `TOP`, `BOTTOM`, `LEFT` and `RIGHT` has something to do with defining formatting. What made use of that `X-SAS-WINDOW` data?

Can I delete those from the header? If I left it there, will it cause any problems? Perhaps when it is indexed by search engines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I don’t know much about how Claris Home Page rendered pages, but `<X-SAS-WINDOW>` is definitely not a valid HTML tag since any tag that is prefixed by `X-` is an “unstandardized” element and [the use of `X-` prefix on custom tags such as those has been depreciated since at least 2012](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6648).

It *might* just be a tag used internally by Claris Home Page—for things like window positioning on the desktop—but that’s it. I was able [to find this Japanese page](https://wiki.suikawiki.org/n/x-sas-window) that clearly states when translated:

> 非標準 (Non-standard)

And shows that `<X-SAS-WINDOW>` tag paired with `<!--This file created 02.5.11 10:31 AM by Claris Home Page version 2.0J-->` so I am fairly confident that is a useless tag as far as standard HTML pages go and can be removed.

That said, since HTML pages are just text pages, I would encourage you to just make an archive of the site as it currently is before you make adjustments and then just remove the `X-SAS-WINDOW` stuff stuff for now when updating the site.

And if you are still unsure, just take the page and run it through an [HTML validator such as this one](https://validator.w3.org).

Answer (score 1):

I used Claris Home Page a lot back in the Classic Mac OS days. So I have a fair number of HTML files lying around with `X-SAS` in it, even to this day. Indeed, `X-SAS-WINDOW` merely records the location of the editor window on the user's Mac OS desktop.

Additionally, there is stuff added to IMG tags:

```
<IMG SRC="images/logo_Insure.gif"
WIDTH=150 HEIGHT=40
X-SAS-UseImageWidth
X-SAS-UseImageHeight
BORDER=0 ALIGN=bottom>
```

In this case, it merely tells the Claris Home Page editor that I didn't scale the image after inserting it. In this way, the editor can automatically update WIDTH and HEIGHT the next time I open the page for editing, if the image alone changes. I always like the fact that Claris Home Page computed WIDTH and HEIGHT automatically in this simple way, because it made page loading smoother in the browser.

This morning I found myself wondering why this stuff wasn't simply stored in the resource fork. I imagine it was because keeping the metadata in sync with the HTML would have been too fragile/complicated, especially if one expects the user to use other editors (e.g., BBEdit) in conjunction.